# httpfs error Operation category READ is not supported in state standby

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, httpfs

I am working on hadoop apache 2.7.1 and I have a cluster that consists of 3 nodes

nn1
nn2
dn1

nn1 is the dfs.default.name, so it is the master name node.

I have installed httpfs and started it of course after restarting all the services. When nn1 is active and nn2 is standby I can send this request

```
http://nn1:14000/webhdfs/v1/aloosh/oula.txt?op=open&user.name=root
```

from my browser and a dialog of *open or save for this file* appears, but when I kill the name node running on nn1 and start it again as normal then because of high availability nn1 becomes standby and nn2 becomes active.

So here httpfs should work, even if nn1 becomes stand by, but sending the same request now

```
http://nn1:14000/webhdfs/v1/aloosh/oula.txt?op=open&user.name=root
```

gives me the error

```
{"RemoteException":{"message":"Operation category READ is not supported in state standby","exception":"RemoteException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException"}}
```

Shouldn't httpfs overcome nn1 standby status and bring the file? Is that because of a wrong configuration, or is there any other reason?

My `core-site.xml` is

```
<property>
       <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
                <value>*</value>
       </property>

        <property>
                <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
                <value>*</value>
        </property>
```

Comment: Assuming `nn1` is where HttpFs server is running, can you confirm whether either one of the node is in active state.

Comment: nn1 is stand by and nn2 is active i can know through hdfs haadmin -getServiceState

Comment: I have the same problem and I checked status of my namenodes by running `hdfs haadmin -getAllServiceState` but the problem persists nevertheless returned state is "active" for one of namenodes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like `HttpFs` is not High Availability aware yet. This could be due to the missing configurations required for the Clients to connect with the current Active Namenode.

Ensure the `fs.defaultFS` property in `core-site.xml` is configured with the correct `nameservice ID`.

If you have the below in `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
  <value>mycluster</value>
</property>
```

then in `core-site.xml`, it should be

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://mycluster</value>
</property>
```

Also configure the name of the Java class which will be used by the DFS Client to determine which NameNode is the currently Active and is serving client requests.

Add this property to `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.mycluster</name>            
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
</property>
```

Restart the Namenodes and HttpFs after adding the properties in all nodes.

Comment: Can I use in cluster name characters like "_-." ? I use HDP 2.6.3 and I set cluster name during installation to my_dev_env, but in hdfs-site.xml is by default mydevenv, is that okay? Also I didn't setup httpfs, only HDFS HA, but these properties was set up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is solving this issue, but solved mine when I was accessing HDFS via HDFS client and it was constantly logging warning about reading in standby mode. I changed following property in hdfs-site.xml for HDFS client:

```
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.uniza-hdfs-ha</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
  </property>
```

to

```
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.uniza-hdfs-ha</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.RequestHedgingProxyProvider</value>
  </property>
```

It is also mentioned in official documentation https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.4/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html