# HttpFs benefit over high availability and nameservice

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs, httpfs

I am using Apache Hadoop-2.7.1 on cluster that consists of three nodes

```
nn1 master name node 
nn2 (second name node)   
dn1 (data node)
```

we know that if we configure high availability in this cluster

we will have two main nodes, one is active and another is standby

and if  we configure the cluster to be called by name service too the following scenario will be ok

the scenario is:

1- nn1 is active and nn2 is stand by

so if we want to get file(called myfile) from dn1  we can send this url from browser (webhdfs request)

http://nn1/webhdfs/v1/hadoophome/myfile/?user.name=root&op=OPEN

2- name node daemon in nn1 is killed so according to high availability nn1 is standby and nn2 is active
so we can get  myfile now  by  sending this web request  to nn2 because it is active now

http://nn2/webhdfs/v1/hadoophome/myfile/?user.name=root&op=OPEN

so configuring name service with high availability is enough for name node failure and for webhdfs to work fine then

so what is the benefit of adding httpfs here 
because webhdfs with high availibility is not supported and we have to configure 
httpfs

Comment: Could you load balance /reverse proxy in front and have it decide to send to either nn1 or nn2?

Comment: you mean that  when we  rely on name service  we don't have to know ip addresses of two name nodes and there is no webhdfs command to test their status , so we depend on httpfs which is fixed on specific host ,but if we are handling webhdfs from external application and that is my state we can redirect our request to another name node  if the request to one of them throws an exception on port 50070 (which is currently standby or turned off),becuase we in advance know their ips ,so here httpfs will have no benifit  ,isn't it

Comment: @Scovetta yes that is an option, but Hadoop provides `HttpFs` to get that done.

Comment: load balance name nodes annd using webhdfs is potentially benefitting than using httpFs in terms of performance, unless you don't want to expose all the datanodes to outside you hadoop cluster. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that this is a follow up of your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340226/httpfs-error-operation-category-read-is-not-supported-in-state-standby).

**`WebHDFS`** and **`HttpFs`** are two different things. **WebHDFS** is part of the Namenode and it is the NN that handles the `WebHDFS` API calls whereas **HttpFs** is a separate service independent of the Namenodes and the `HttpFs` server handles the API calls.

> what is the benefit of adding httpfs

Your REST API calls will remain the same irrespective of which NN is in Active state. `HttpFs`, being HA aware, will direct the request to the current Active NN.

Let us assume `HttpFs` server is started in `nn1`.

**WebHDFS** `GET` request

```
curl http://nn1:50070/webhdfs/v1/hadoophome/myfile/?user.name=root&op=OPEN
```

This is served by the Namenode daemon running in `nn1`. 
**Scenario 1:** `nn1` is Active. The request will be rewarded with a valid response. 
**Scenario 2:** `nn2` is Active. Making the same request will fail as there is no Active NN running in `nn1`.

So, the REST call must be modified to request the `nn2`

```
curl http://nn2:50070/webhdfs/v1/hadoophome/myfile/?user.name=root&op=OPEN
```

Now, this will be served by the NN daemon running in `nn2`.

**HttpFs** `GET` request

```
curl http://nn1:14000/webhdfs/v1/hadoophome/myfile/?user.name=root&op=OPEN
```

This request is served by the `HttpFs` service running in `nn1`.
**Scenario 1:** `nn1` is Active. `HttpFs` server running in `nn1` will direct the request to the current Active Namenode `nn1`.
**Scenario 2:** `nn2` is Active. `HttpFs` server running in `nn1` will direct the request to the current Active Namenode `nn2`.

In both scenario, the REST call is same. The request will fail if the `HttpFs` server is down.

> configuring name service with high availability is enough for name
>   node failure and for webhdfs to work fine

`nameservice` is the logical name given to the pair of Namenodes. This `nameservice` is not an actual Host and cannot be replaced with the Host parameter in the REST API calls.