# How to track HDFS Active Namenode change event in NiFi?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-nifi, namenode

I have HDFS cluster with Active and Stanby Namenodes.
Sometimes when cluster gets restarted, Namenodes exchange their roles - Standby becomes Active, and vice versa.

Then I have NiFi flow with PutParquet processor writing some files to this HDFS cluster. 
Processor is configured with directory property as "hdfs://${namenode}/some/path", where ${namenode} variable value is like "first.namenode.host.com:8020".

Now, when cluster gets restarted and actual Namenode gets changed to "second.namenode.host.com:8020", configuration in NiFi is not updated and processor still tries to use old namenode address, and thus some exception is thrown (I don't remember actual error text, but I think it doesn't matter for my question).

And now the question is: how can I track this event in NiFi, to automatically update PutParqet processor configuration when HDFS configuration changed?

NiFi version is 1.6.0, HDFS version is 2.6.0-cdh5.8.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't confirmed this, but I thought with HA HDFS (Active and Standby NNs), you'd have the HA properties set in your *-site.xml files (probably core-site.xml) and would refer to the "cluster name" which the Hadoop client will then resolve into a list of NameNodes, which it would then try to connect to. If that's the case, then try the cluster name (see the core-site.xml file on the cluster) rather than a hardcoded NN address.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that you could do:

- If you know the IP address or hostname of the two name nodes, you can try this: Connect the failure relationship of `PutParquet` and connect it to either `UpdateAttribute` and change the directory value if you're using NiFi expressions for `Directory` property or another `PutParquet` processor with the directory value configured with the standby name node.
- You could use PutHDFS but I'm not sure if PutParquet offers better performance over PutHDFS

Comment: PutHDFS and PutParquet both have Directory property, and I think both expect "hdfs://${namenode}/some/path" as value of this property, so what are the differences between them?
And what is the output format of PutHDFS? How to force it to write Parquet files? I don't see any properties for that...

Comment: You should be able to specify the directory as a "/some/path" and it will be at the root of the file system based on whatever is configured in core-site.xml for the default file system. I think you only need the hdfs:// prefix if you are writing to a different filesystem than the default.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have solved my problem. But that was not a "problem" at all :) here is the solution: [httpfs error Operation category READ is not supported in state standby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340226/httpfs-error-operation-category-read-is-not-supported-in-state-standby).

I had not to track event of changing active namenode manually within NiFi, instead of this I just had to configure my Hadoop client properly with core-site.xml to force it to get actual namenode automatically.

So the solution is just to set property "fs.defaultFS" in core-site.xml to the value of property "dfs.nameservices" from hdfs-site.xml (in my case "fs.defaultFS" in core-site.xml pointed to the actual host of active namenode - "first.namenode.host.com:8020").

I say "seems" because I have not tested this solution yet. But using this approach I can write to HDFS cluster without setting active hanemode address anywhere in NiFi. I just set it to use some "nameservice" rather then actual address, so I think if actual address changes - probably this does not affect NiFi, and Hadoop client handles this event.

Later I'm going to test it.

Thanks to @mattyb for an idea!