# pySpark job failing on yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

i am trying submit pyspark job from yarnclient. getting below error from RM without any further logs.

> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException):
> Operation category READ is not supported in state standby ENOENT: No
> such file or directory at
> org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmodImpl(Native Method)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:231)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:773)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.DelegateToFileSystem.setPermission(DelegateToFileSystem.java:218)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFs.setPermission(FilterFs.java:266) at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$11.next(FileContext.java:1008) at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$11.next(FileContext.java:1004) at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90) at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.setPermission(FileContext.java:1011)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$3.run(FSDownload.java:483)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$3.run(FSDownload.java:481)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1875)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.changePermissions(FSDownload.java:481)
> at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:419) at
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.doDownloadCall(ContainerLocalizer.java:242)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.call(ContainerLocalizer.java:235)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.call(ContainerLocalizer.java:223)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) For more detailed output,
> check the application tracking page:
> https://.com:8090/cluster/app/application_1638972290118_64750
> Then click on links to logs of each attempt. . Failing the
> application.

cluster is fine and other pyspark jobs running fine.
Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: As output says, `For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: https://.... Then click on links to logs of each attempt`. Please give the more detailed logs

Comment: when go to application tracking page, it says org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "***cluster is fine and other pyspark jobs running fine***"?
Did you run them on Yarn or just on Standalone mode?

However, I think it's better to check your yarn cluster first to see if it works (without spark).
you can do it using hadoop MapR examples:

`yarn jar $HadoopDir/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-$version.jar wordcount inputFilePath OutputDir`

Check [link 1](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/ls-Operation-category-READ-is-not-supported-in-state-standby/td-p/61578) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340226/httpfs-error-operation-category-read-is-not-supported-in-state-standby) too. They may help.

Comment: spark jobs submitted from spark-submit command working fine

Comment: usually what is the root cause of that error